# interpreting rank difference trend

Tags: model, ranking

I am doing some research utilizing popularity ranks in periodic data. I've been able to model the rank data using Zipf Law effectively. I am interested in understanding how the rank changes, as well. When I consider two consecutive periods and compute the rank difference of items that occur in both periods, I get a very distinct pattern in the log-linear plot. It differs slightly by data source and period width, but overall is bi-modal with a difference of a fraction of log N, e.g., 0.3.

I would like to understand how I might compute the fraction consistently and why it occurs. I don't find an obvious correlation with the Zipf exponents I've found. In the picture below, I've taken two adjacent periods, so the underlying data does not overlap, then for items that occur in the top ranks of both periods, i've computed the rank change. the x-axis is the rank from period one.

I interpret this plot as: the lower your rank in the first period, the more likely it will be further away in the second period, that is, rank is repellant across periods as a constant times rank, if that makes sense. And, you are more likely to become less popular than more popular (not surprising).

I don't really understand the cause for the bimodal aspect and i don't understand why it changes like a fraction of r, i.e., cr.

[image: rank change]